# Getting "Null" output from package?

Tags: functions, syntax, packages

I have a script written to test a package as follows:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
<< test`

A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
cp = CharacteristicPolynomial[A, L]
sol = Sum[L[n, cp], {n, 0, 1}]
```

Which outputs "L+ Null".

The package is as follows:

```
BeginPackage["test`"]

L::usage="description goes here"

Begin["`Private`"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

L[n0_,cp0_]:=
    Module[{n=n0,cp=cp0},
    L[n_,cp_]:=
        L[n,cp]=
            Which[
                n==0,L[0]=1,
                n==1,L[1]=L,
                n==2,L[2]=Simplify[-(cp-L^2)],
                n>2 && EvenQ[n]==True,L[n]=Simplify[L[n/2] L[n/2]],
                n>2 && EvenQ[n]==False,L[n]=Simplify[L[n-1] L[1]]
                ]
]

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Essentially, my function "L[ ]" has 4 possible outputs:
when n=0  L[0]=1,
when n=1, L[1]=L,
when n=2, L[2]=Simplify[-(cp-L^2)]
when n>2 and even, L[n]=Simplify[L[n/2] L[n/2]]
when n>2 and odd, L[n]=Simplify[L[n-1] L[1]]

Why is L[0,cp]= Null, when all of the other possibilities work?
If I try just L[0,cp] (no Sum[ ]) I receive no output. What does that mean?
Is Which[ ] the best method of approach in this situation?

Comment: I would start with a single question and a minimal working example. Does having it as a package change anything? Are you sure you know, what are you doing with `L[0]=1` etc.?

Comment: Check `Definition["L"]` and see, if it outputs what you expect.

Comment: `ClearAll["Global`*"]` in a package???

Comment: The function looks rather bizarre to me. Memoization (`L[n_,cp_]:= L[n,cp]=...)`inside a scoping construct using the same variable names and then the whole Module SetDelayed to L again... Note that the `n` in `Which` is bound to the `n` in `L[n_,cp_]` and is not the same as the `n` in the `Module` variable list. So the first time it is called non of the `Which` tests is true and it returns Null.

Comment: If I implement as just a function:  
L[n_, cp_] :=
   L[n, cp] =
     Which[
       n == 1, L[1] = L,
       n == 0, L[0] = 1,
       n == 2, L[2] = Simplify[-(cp - L^2)],
       n > 2 && EvenQ[n] == True,            
   L[n] = Simplify[L[n/2] L[n/2]],
       n > 2 && EvenQ[n] == False, L[n] = Simplify[L[n - 1] L[1]]
       ]
  
I get the correct output for any n.

@Sjoerd C. de Vries I'm going to be honest, I have no idea what you are talking about. I'm be the first to admit I'm a beginner when it comes to Mathematica. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In your comment you left away the first definition of L and the Module. That makes a difference. Why are you surprised by that? And, did you use memoization on purpose?

Comment: No, it's the same definition of L.  I'm not surprised by anything considering I don't really know what I'm doing... That's why I'm asking - what am I doing wrong? This is the format of the Package which I'm adding-on to that someone else wrote.  I was assuming I could write my function following their formatting and add it to their Package.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your last question - no, I didn't use memoization on purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here. I'll start with the little problems.

First, `EvenQ` returns `True` or `False`. You don't need to test whether `EvenQ` is true, so `EvenQ[n]==True` is redundantly redundant.

Next, what is `L` compared to `L[n,cp]`? Or `L[1]`? If your output in the second case of the `Which` is meant to be the function symbol `L` without any arguments specified, okay, but do you really mean `L0` or some other initial value? Because you should use another symbol for that.

This need not be a module. A module allows you to define a routine that uses local variables and more complex programming techniques that operate on local variables. The only local variables you use are the inputs -- reassigned to be local variables.

The reason you don't want this to be a module, especially, is that your definition is:

```
L[n0_, cp0_] := Module[{n = n0, cp = cp0}, L[n_, cp_] := L[n, cp] =
```

That's one `:=` too many. You don't even need memoization because (as far as I can tell) this is not meant to be recursive. The function `L[_][_]` seems to be constructed in a way that it assigns values to the (overloaded) function `L[_]`. Other comments have addressed this issue and have noted this is why you are not getting any output.

If you make the following changes, you'll have something functional (pun intended?):

```
L[n_?IntegerQ, cp_?IntegerQ] :=
 Which[
  n == 0, L[0] = 1,
  n == 1, L[1] = L,
  n == 2, L[2] = Simplify[-(cp - L^2)],
  n > 2 && EvenQ[n], L[n] = Simplify[L[n/2] L[n/2]],
  n > 2, L[n] = Simplify[L[n - 1] L[1]]
 ]
```

This function will only take integer inputs (that's what the `?IntegerQ` will do). It will output some expression of other `L` functions. For example, `L[3,7]` will output `L[1]L[2]`.

Now, you've still overloaded the symbol `L` substantially. Why is a two-argument `L[3,7]` giving us `L[1]L[2]`, which is a product of some other type of `L` that takes only one argument?

I'm under the impression that we can fix this code so that it works, but it's not really doing what we want. I hope we've cleared up the technical issues, but we need to start from scratch.

**EDIT: You can skip to the addendum here if you want to cut to the chase.**

Mathematically, you seem to just one a single sequence `L` that is determined by some integer parameter `cp`. You can do this in a much more reasonable way by thinking of it this way:

For any integer $cp$, you have a sequence $L_n^{cp}$ that is defined recursively. You can write the appropriate code as follows:

```
L[cp_?IntegerQ][n_?IntegerQ] := L[cp][n] =
 Which[
  n == 0, 1,
  n == 1, L[cp][0],
  n == 2, L[cp][0]^2 - cp,
  n > 2 && EvenQ[n], Simplify[L[cp][n/2]^2],
  True, L[cp][n - 1] L[cp][1]
 ]
```

I've taken some liberty by using `L[cp][0]` instead of the no-argument `L`. You'll have to figure out what goes there. If that is some other parameter, you probably ought to give it a different name like `\[Lambda]` or something. (It would play a similar role as cp.)

This uses a sort of double-function, rather than two-argument function, for technical reasons. You could replace every occurrence of `L[_][_]` with `L[_,_]`, but for programmatic reasons I think it's better the `[_][_]` way.

Try this to experiment:

```
Manipulate[Table[L[cp][n], {n, 1, 10}], {{cp, 1}, -10, 10, 1}]
```

On second thought, I'd like to pretend now that maybe this `L` with no arguments is a parameter. Let's not call it `L` to avoid confusion. Your code might look like:

```
L[cp_?IntegerQ, \[Lambda]_?IntegerQ][n_?IntegerQ] :=
 L[cp, \[Lambda]][n] =
 Which[
  n == 0, 1,
  n == 1, \[Lambda],
  n == 2, \[Lambda]^2 - cp,
  n > 2 && EvenQ[n], Simplify[L[cp, \[Lambda]][n/2]^2],
  True, L[cp, \[Lambda]][n - 1] L[cp, \[Lambda]][1]
 ]

Manipulate[
 Table[L[cp, \[Lambda]][n], {n, 1, 10}],
 {{cp, 1}, -10, 10, 1}, {{\[Lambda], 1}, -10, 10, 1}
]
```

**ADDENDUM:**

Upon further review, I didn't even read your example code (sorry, I am lazy sometimes in the worst ways). Apparently cp is a polynomial. In this case, why does it not have an argument? Based on this, here is my revised code:

I will say, in my opinion, this probably doesn't belong in an external file/package. And if it does, I think I would be cautious with the ClearAll[`Global`*]`. I suggest you remove that, at least, if not just putting everything into a single notebook for now.

I think I have finally deciphered exactly what you're trying to do.

Let's start from scratch, mathematically. You have a matrix $A$. This matrix has a characteristic polynomial, a function of $\lambda$. You have integers $n$ that will define some functions of $\lambda$ for each $n$. These are *not* functions of $cp$. They are functions of $A$ and $n$.

The sequence of polynomial functions of $\lambda$ you want are defined by:

$L_{A,0}(\lambda)=0$

$L_{A,1}(\lambda)=\lambda$

$L_{A,2}(\lambda)=\lambda^2-p_A(\lambda)$

$L_{A,2n}(\lambda)=L_{A,n}(\lambda)^2$

$L_{A,2n+1}(\lambda)=L_{A,2n}(\lambda)L_{A,1}(\lambda)$

This can be achieved by:

```
L[A_, n_] := L[A, n] =
 Function[\[Lambda],
  Which[
   n == 0, 1,
   n == 1, \[Lambda],
   n == 2, \[Lambda]^2 - CharacteristicPolynomial[A, \[Lambda]],
   n > 2 && EvenQ[n], Simplify[L[A, n/2][\[Lambda]]^2],
   True, L[A, n - 1][\[Lambda]] L[A, 1][\[Lambda]]
  ]
 ]

A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
Table[L[A, n][\[Lambda]], {n, 0, 10}]
sol = Plus @@ %
Expand[%]
```

That should do whatever it is you're trying to do... I think.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted. I'll just forget about the package for now, and place everything into a notebook. Thanks also for showing how to use \[Lambda], I didn't know you could do that (hence the use of "L").